# Stop Sidekiq gracefully while terminating Autoscale EC2 instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, sidekiq, autoscaling

I am facing issue with aws autoscaling + sidekiq busy jobs. I have 4 instances are running in auto scale group and multiple Sidekiq processes are running on these instances. All instances using same **redis**.

If one of my instance is terminating at that time the jobs in his busy queue pushed into failed state. It should enqueued this jobs.

I have added one script in /etc/rc0.d folder which will kill sidekiq processes at the time of instace termination, but still my jobs are going in the failure state.
I tried with TERM and USR1 signal for sidkeiq process termination  but same thing happened with this signals.

I have used sidkeiq pro also enabled the reliable fetch.

Does anyone know, how to achieve the jobs in the busy queue should go into enqueued not in faliure state while killig sidekiq process manually or gracefully ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue myself and had to fix it by fully plumbing it into the daemon management, in my case chkconfig.  I'm not sure what your EC2 setup is like, but I found that only scripts that chkconfig knew about were being executed.

If you don't already, you may also need to add a sleep to the script to ensure Sidekiq has enough time to fully exit.

Comment: pls post a sample script and how you used chkconfig to plumb into the daemon managment. I am using elastic beanstalk and sidekiq, but don't worry, your script and daemon plumbig will only acts as a guide for me. thanks

Comment: I'm not allowed to share the code, but the essential structure that I wrote is that the service starts when Sidekiq starts, then it executes Sidekiq's graceful shutdown when it detects the host system shutting down, rebooting, etc.

Comment: If your system uses chkconfig or something similar, you'll want to create the script in /etc/init.d/.  You can read how to write the script here: [link](http://shahmirj.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-creating-a-daemon-in-linux)

Comment: In 'start', I ended up just creating the lock file for the service.

Comment: In 'stop' if a pid file is present for Sidekiq, then my code executes `kill -TERM [pid]`.  If that is successful, it removes the pid file and pauses 10 seconds to allow any workers that are still running to either complete or get pushed back into the queue.

Comment: Once you've completed the script file, you'll want to add it to chkconfig with `sudo chkconfig --add [name of script file]`.

Comment: Forgot to mention the runlevels.  I never got them to work the way I was expecting them to work.  You may want to call `sudo /etc/init.d/[name of script file] start` in whatever starts Sidekiq to ensure that it is running.